# Import Data from Excel using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis

I have an Excel data source with 9 sheets. If I set the connection manager's `RetainSameConnetion = True`, the import takes seconds. If I set the property to `False` then it takes about a minute. So far so good. However, at the end of the package I want to move the Excel file to an archive folder. If the `RetainSameConnection` is set to True the file is locked and can't be moved.

Is there a way in a script to release the connection so that the file can be moved at the end. I've tried `DTS.Connections("xxxx").ReleaseConnection(y)` but that doesn't seem to work, whatever I set the value of y to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to this as SSIS is designed to have different aspects of jobs broken out into multiple packages and therefore the connection should not need to be dropped within the package it is created in.

This is based around the Project deployment model, and is by design as Microsoft loves to say.

Now this is a really hacky way to do it but since no one else is taking a stab at it I will give it a shot.

You will need to create a dummy variable (boolean is best).

Set the retainsameconnection property expression for your connection manager to an expression that evaluates to true. ( variable == true)

Add a script task right before you need to move the file to the archive and change the value of your boolean variable to the opposite of its default.

Upon the completion of your script task your retainsameconnection should now be evaluated as false and the connection should drop.

If all goes well the connection manager should no longer want to retain that connection for the entirety of the package execution.

Not sure if the version of Bids or SSDT you are running will allow for live evaluation of that property but it is worth a shot.